# php/css/html language buttons current language

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, qtranslate

I have "buttons", which change language on the web-page:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="button-link" href= "<?php echo qtrans_convertURL(get_permalink(), 'de'); ?>" target="_parent">DE</a>
    <a class="button-link" href="<?php echo qtrans_convertURL(get_permalink(), 'en'); ?>" target="_parent">EN</a>
</div>
```

And I make a hover effect, to show, which language is about to be chosen:

```css
.button-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e95252;
}
```

Now I am trying to keep this border line under the chosen language. So that the user always sees the active language. I thought it would be as simple as:

```css
.button-link:active{}
```

But it doesn't work the way I want it, so I guess I have to write a php function. I have found examples of how to show the current page, but it is not the same as with the languages. Because the language button is independent of the page, it should always stay underlined if a person has chosen English, for example.

Comment: The way to do it could be making a function in php, and setting its result in the a class, like `<a class="<?= myFunction()?>">...`;

Comment: You don't have any behavior inside the `.button-link:active{}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing the following
PHP:

```
<?php if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='de'): ?>
<a class="button-link active" href= "<?php echo qtrans_convertURL(get_permalink(), 'de'); ?>"
       target="_parent">DE</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
   border-bottom: 2px solid #e95252;
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This code works perfectly, thank you a lot! I've added "elseif" for other languages, and have inserted the "not active" buttons of other languages in each "if"/"elseif".

Comment: Glad I could help I would appreciate if you could select and vote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this, would be to add a `class="<?= $lang = 'de' ? 'active' : '' ?>"` to every `.button-link`. Since they are all doing the same it would be simpler:

```
<?php
    $langs = array('de', 'fr', 'it', 'en');
?>

<div class="wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($langs as $lang) : ?>
        <a class="button-link" href="<?= qtrans_convertURL(get_permalink(), $lang); ?>" class="<?= qtrans_getLanguage() == $lang ? 'active-lang' : '' ?>" target="_parent"><?= strtoupper($lang); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

and in css you would simply select the class either as

```
.active-lang {}
```

or

```
.button-link.active-lang {}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a really good idea to make a loop around it, I'll work on it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this can be done:
define new class>

```
.button-link-active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e95252;
}
```

then use following code to add class in your link:

```
<?php if ( qtrans_getLanguage() == "en" ){ echo "button-link-active" } ?>
```

final code will be like this:

```
<a class="button-link <?php if ( qtrans_getLanguage() == "en" ){ echo "button-link-active" } ?> " href= "<?php echo qtrans_convertURL(get_permalink(), 'de'); ?>" target="_parent">DE</a>
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to use single quotes in final code.....inside class=" .. "
change all double to single quotes.

Comment: and also semicolon ; after echo statement :) 
it is happening because i am using python from long time.